# What is a protected states in Supersymmetry, Superstring theory context

Tags: supersymmetry, ads-cft, supergravity

I know that they are the states that have protected scaling dimension when couplings are changed. But there are some states that are protected only in free orbifold theory, this is something I don't quite understand. What does it mean for a state to be protected in free orbifold theory? Because to check if they are protected in free orbifold theory, we change the coupling that makes us move away from the free orbifold point doesn't it?

Comment: Do you mean in the T^4 symmetric orbifold theory?

Comment: Yes, more precisely in N copies T^4 and symmetrised by permutation group S_N